# Object Serialization

Tags: c#, object-serialization

Assume object A has 6 fields, now the object A is serialized, after some time the 3 more fields are added and the object is deserialized.

1. Adding of the new fields will create any exception when deserializing.
2. How to have a backward compatibility

Answer (score 5):

Read [Version Tolerant Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Generally add a version and implement custom serialization via ISerializable.

Handle appropriate defaults and or throw more appropriate exceptions there.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28VS.80%29.aspx#Y1733)

Answer (score 0):

.Net has something called "Version Tolerant Serialization" ;)

Check out this easy to understand example on object serialization:

http://programming.flashadventures.com/c-sharp/writing-objects-to-files-serialization/

Comment: looks more like a promotion than a answer to me. Website says coming soon ?